# Java - Clean file path

Tags: java, path

I want to clean the path I use in my App. The path can be modified and sometimes I got something like that:

```
C:/users/Username/Desktop/\..\..\..\Windows\Web\..\..\Program Files\..\Program Files\..\Python27\
```

But I would like to have something like:

```
C:\Python27\
```

That's an example!

How can I clean the path to get only the necessary part?

Thanks.

Comment: So what is the criteria for the cleaned path?
Only the part after the last '\'?

Comment: Here is the code I use (Without the clean path) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204722/java-exec-console/10205644#10205644

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `fileName` is your filename string, then something like:

```
String cleanedFilename = new File(fileName).getCanonicalPath();
```

should do it...

Se also the [API description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath%28%29).

Comment: Does not work for all. For instance:
input = "/Whatever/mette_e1.mastodon/..\dataset_DataStoreAlfeios.xml";
canonical = "/Whatever/mette_e1.mastodon/..\dataset_DataStoreAlfeios.xml";

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the File.getCanonicalPath() method:

```
File file = new File("my/init/path");
String path = file.getCanonicalPath();
```

I haven't test though, tell us back!

**EDIT:**
@MathiasSchwarz is right, use getCanonicalPath() instead of getAbsolutePath() ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099300/whats-the-difference-between-getpath-getabsolutepath-and-getcanonicalpath))

Comment: `getAbsolutePath` is not required to remove `..` and `.`. The only guarantee is the that the path returned is not relative.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code I have just tried.

`new File("c:/temp/..").getCanonicalPath();`

It returns 'C:\', that is right. The parent of `c:/temp` is indeed `c:\`